# Regex for a decimal number

Tags: javascript, regex

I used the following regex

```
var x=32423332.343;
var res= x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

which gives an output of 32,423,332.343

How do I modify this regex (shortest way) to get the following output

3,24,23,332.343

Comment: Are you sure you want such a format!? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Jerry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Numbering_System

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker It's really a first for me...

Comment: @TimPietzcker that format is the most common format used, so you will find it everywhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want that, you can modify your regex a bit:

```
\B(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?!\d))
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uG3sH6)

`(?:\d{2})*` will match even number of digits before the final `\d{3}`.

For PCRE engine, one that can handle integers and floating, with `g` enabled.

```
\G\d{1,2}\K\B(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?!\d))
```

Comment: @user1814374 You're welcome! Thanks to you, I learned something new today as well ;)